# Reading environment variables from more than one ".env" file in Python

Tags: python, git, environment-variables

I have environment variables that I need to get from two different files in order to keep user+pw outside of the git repo. I download the sensitive user+pass from another location and add it to .gitignore.

I am using

```py
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    ...
    load_dotenv()
    DB_HOST=getenv('DB_HOST') # from env file 1
    DB_NAME=getenv('DB_NAME') # from env file 1
    DB_USER=getenv('DB_USER') # from env file 2
    DB_PASS=getenv('DB_PASS') # from env file 2
```

and I have the two ".env" files in the folder of the python script.

env_file.env contains:

```sh
DB_HOST=xyz
DB_NAME=abc
```

env_file_in_gitignore.env which needs to stay out of the git repo but is available by download using an sh script:

```sh
DB_USER=me
DB_PASS=eao
```

How to avoid the error:

```
TypeError: connect() argument 2 must be str, not None
connect() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

which is thrown since one of the two files are not used for the .env import?

How can I get environment variables from two different ".env" files, both stored in the working directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add file path as an argument in `load_dotenv` function

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv(<file 1 path>)
load_dotenv(<file 2 path>)
```

Answer (score 4):

I implemented reading env values from multiple env files by using if statements as below.

I put basic stuffs in .env file and local and prod settings in respective .env.local or .env.prod file

```
# Import and load environment variables
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv() # Load .env file

# Need to check and return boolean, so check for String "True"
APP_ENVIRONMENT = os.getenv("DEBUG") == "True"

if APP_ENVIRONMENT:
    load_dotenv(".env.local")
else:
    load_dotenv(".env.prod")
```

Comment: The question was about how to read more than one env file. You make it a choice between two env files, local and prod. That is nice code as well, but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: First it loads .env, then it loads either .env.local or .env.prod -- so it loads 2 env files and provides a good mechanism for switching between local and production.

Answer (score 3):

there is a method load env file is `load_dotenv` you can use as many env file you want using

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('path1')
load_dotenv('path2)
...
```

for more information read [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)